# How can we write if not empty condtion in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Here we can write `if not empty` condition  in codeigniter like this

```
if(!empty($user_id))
    {
             $this->db->where('bills.customerid', $user_id);
    }
```

Like this how i wrote not empty condition in my sql query like this

```
IF($user_id <>'') THEN customerid=$user_id
```

but its getting wrong.How can we write the condition like the codeigniter

Comment: you can do like `field` != '' in mysql. in CI `$this->db->where('bills.customerid !=', "");`

Comment: Like this: `WHERE bills.customerid = 30;`

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie  i want to take `customerid=$user_id` only when `$user_id` is not null

Comment: then do:- `WHERE bills.customerid = $user_id AND $user_id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie this condition becomes true only when  `$user_id IS NOT NULL` and query should run if condition becomes false also..it means if `$user_id` is not null  then `bills.customerid = $user_id`  should run with this condition and if  `$user_id` is null the query should run with out `bills.customerid = $user_id`

Comment: then use CASE:- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Comment: i wrote like this `CASE
    WHEN $user_id IS NOT NULL THEN customerid=$user_id END` but else condition get fails